# Populating RecyclerView with data from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I created a RecyclerView with data loaded locally using a standard model and adapter approach, the views that the RecyclerView recycles hold an image and 3 text views. I'd like to populate these views using data from a Firebase Database. I've created the data on Firebase which looks like this:

```
{
  "items" : {
    "item 1" : {
      "colour-value" : "000000",
      "manufacturer" : "Manufacturer 1",
      "name" : "Name 1",
      "type" : "Type 1"
    },
    "item 2" : {
      "colour-value" : "ffff00",
      "manufacturer" : "Manufacturer 2",
      "name" : "Name 2",
      "type" : "Type 2"
    },
    "item 3" : {
      "colour-value" : "ff0000",
      "manufacturer" : "Manufacturer 3",
      "name" : "Name 3",
      "type" : "Type 3"
    }
  }
}
```

I've already added the dependencies and have Firebase Auth set up and working. The data will never be changed by the user but may be changed manually in the back end from time to time. The image is a single white png with the colour changed based on the colour-value.

Everything that I've seen appears to be overly complex for what I need and I'm convinced it doesn't need to be but can't whittle down what I need to feed this data into the RecyclerView.

Any pointers? Thanks.

EDIT - All special characters have been removed from data.

ItemAdapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Item> itemList;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView itemName, itemManufacturer, itemType;

        private MyViewHolder (View view) {
            super(view);

            itemName = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            itemManufacturer = view.findViewById(R.id.item_manufacturer);
            itemType = view.findViewById(R.id.item_type);
        }
    }

    ItemAdapter(Context mContext, List<Item> itemList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Item.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = itemList.get(position);

    holder.itemName.setText(item.getItemName());
    holder.itemManufacturer.setText(item.getItemManufacturer());
    holder.itemType.setText(item.getItemType());
}

void filter (ArrayList<Item> newList) {
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your current RecyclerView code. Also, I didn't think Firebase keys can have spaces, so is that really the JSON extract?

Comment: Also, seen this? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: you need to change your keys as java won't allow special characters in naming while mapping to POJO.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem here in your JSON you can not have a hyphen or spaces in your keys as firebase will do a mapping based on keys to POJO member variables and java does not allow special characters in namings. 
So if you change your keys just do this 
Make a POJO

```
public class SampleModel {
private int colorValue;
private String manufacturer;
private String name;
private String type;

public int getColorValue() {
    return colorValue;
}

public void setColorValue(int colorValue) {
    this.colorValue = colorValue;
}

public String getManufacturer() {
    return manufacturer;
}

public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
```

}

then create your database reference and get the data and update the list

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //you have data now traverse
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //your data may come up in map so handle here
                HashMap<String,SampleModel> hashMap =  (HashMap<String,SampleModel>)child.getValue();
                //if everything is okay then just iterate over the map and create a list
                List<SampleModel> sampleModels = new ArrayList<>()
                for (HashMap.Entry<String,SampleModel> modelEntry:hashMap.entrySet()){
                    sampleModels.add(modelEntry.getValue());
                }
                mainList.addAll(sampleModels);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //for some reason data did't show up
        }
    });
```

Edit: Added

```
HashMap<String,SampleModel> hashMap =  (HashMap<String,SampleModel>)child.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas, seems to be throwing an error:

`com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class java.util.HashMap has generic type parameters, please use GenericTypeIndicator instead`

Comment: Thanks, no errors but the view is blank. Do the views need to be mapped to the data some how?

Comment: may be there is something wrong in mapping so you need to check if all fields are getting mapped to model properly for that you need to debug, debug the for loop and check what data you are getting from the database

Comment: I've stepped through and made some changes, appears to be working, or at least loading the data properly. My Adapter appears to be throwing an error now (I've added to the question above) does it need to be handled differently?

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.myapp.myapp.Item`

Comment: There's an unchecked cast warning on the HashMap line too